# java Scanner reads one every two values

Tags: java

Ok, so this piece of code is supposed to read input from the user using a scanner (named reader here) and write it to a file. The issue here is that the Scanner is reading, with no exceptions, only one every to values... so if the user enters " 1" , "2", "3" , "4" only "2" and "4" are saved to the file.
No exceptions.

Also it's necessary to write "quit" two times to break the loop, depending if the number of items added is even or odd...

Why is this happening? Any ideas?

```
while (reader.hasNext()) {

            String valor = null;
            // We check for a "quit" to stop adding items to the array list..
            if (reader.next().equals("quit")){
                break;
            } else {

            valor = reader.next();

            fileManaging arxiu = new fileManaging();
            fileManaging.createFile(valor);



            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are consuming the scanner twice per iteration by calling `reader.next()` twice.

Try instead:

```
String valor = reader.next();
if (!valor.equals("quit")) {
    fileManaging arxiu = new fileManaging();
    fileManaging.createFile(valor);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

change below code:

```
if (reader.next().equals("quit")){
            break;
        } else {

valor = reader.next();
```

with this:

```
valor = reader.next();
if (valor.equals("quit")){
            break;
        } else {
```